# Hosts file edit taking a long time to work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, hosts

Whenever I add an entry to the Hosts file on Windows, it takes a long time for the change to take place? I have tested using Firefox and IE and it seems to take around 5 minutes on both of them before the new IP/Domain entry on Hosts is recognised.

Is there anything I can do to overcome this? Perhaps "refreshing" the cache in some way? ipconfig /flushdns doesn't work.

Comment: Many browsers have their own DNS cache I think. There's an addon for firefox to flush the dns cache and maybe you can disable it as well, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to close all browser windows after you edited the hosts file.
(Make sure all IE processed are quit).

Answer (score 0):

I made an entry into the Host file. It was not effective. Two days later, I tried an experiment. My Firefox browser cache was near its 500MB limit. I emptied the cache and immediately tested the Host file, again. It worked.

While this may not be a solution in all cases, it was in mine.